# How do I delete all the resources within the subnet in cli?

Tags: azure-cli

Every time that I try to delete a subnet I got this type of error "Subnet testVMSubnet is in use by /subscriptions/testVMVMNic/ipConfigurations/ipconfigtestVM and cannot be deleted. In order to delete the subnet, delete all the resources within the subnet. See aka.ms/deletesubnet."

So, how do I delete all the resources within the subnet?

```
[
  {
    "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
    "addressPrefixes": null,
    "delegations": [],
    "etag": "W/\"ba1ae732-1aa2-4d6d-af04-3dc6eaac8338\"",
    "id": "/subscriptions/23c7f465-e27b-418b-b8a7-21616582f9bb/resourceGroups/user-qkyosxgoenbq/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/testVMVNET/subnets/testVMSubnet",
    "interfaceEndpoints": null,
    "ipConfigurationProfiles": null,
    "ipConfigurations": [
      {
        "etag": null,
        "id": "/subscriptions/23c7f465-e27b-418b-b8a7-21616582f9bb/resourceGroups/user-qkyosxgoenbq/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/testVMVMNic/ipConfigurations/ipconfigtestVM",
        "name": null,
        "privateIpAddress": null,
        "privateIpAllocationMethod": null,
        "provisioningState": null,
        "publicIpAddress": null,
        "resourceGroup": "user-qkyosxgoenbq",
        "subnet": null
      }
    ],
    "name": "testVMSubnet",
    "networkSecurityGroup": null,
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "purpose": null,
    "resourceGroup": "user-qkyosxgoenbq",
    "resourceNavigationLinks": null,
    "routeTable": null,
    "serviceAssociationLinks": null,
    "serviceEndpointPolicies": null,
    "serviceEndpoints": null,
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this. If you have Network Watcher running in the region where your vnet is located than you can get the topology mapping to find out what is attached to that subnet [using the command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/watcher?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-watcher-show-security-group-view) `az network watcher show-topology -g MyResourceGroup`. In addition to being only a single region, this only shows resource within a single resource group- items attached to the subnet from a different resource group won't show.

Theoretically you could parse this in order to create a list of delete scripts but this would be rather complex as each resource type has a different command to remove it. The solution depends greatly on how often you need to do this and scale. If it's a one-off, getting the list and manually deleting each item is probably simplest whether you do it from the portal or the cli. For an automated solution you may want to delete and redeploy the resource group or create a cleanup script to compliment your deployment scripts.